# Redeploy Solution to SharePoint 2007 using STSADM

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-deployment

So I have used the following command to deploy a solution to SharePoint as I am a new commer to SharePoint developement.

stsadm -o addsolution -filename Demo.wsp

I used WSPBuilder to build the wsp file which just contains one web part.  What do I do deploy the new wsp file.  When I try using the same command above I get the error.

a solution with the same name "Demo.wsp" or id "blahblah" already exists in the solution store

Answer (score 3):

Use `stsadm -o upgradesolution -filename <localwsp> -name <solutionname>` -- but remember that the solutionid must be the same for both the new and the current WSPs (this is normally the case unless you're doing something a bit weird.)

-Oisin